# IndexError: index 40 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 40

Tags: python-3.6

I got this error, can someone gives any suggestions

```
    selected_columns = selected_columns[1:].values
    import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
    def backwardElimination(x, Y, sl, columns):
        numVars = len(x[0])
        for i in range(0, numVars):
            regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(Y, x).fit()
            maxVar = max(regressor_OLS.pvalues).astype(float)
            if maxVar > sl:
                 for j in range(0, numVars - i):
                    if (regressor_OLS.pvalues[j].astype(float) == maxVar):
                        x = np.delete(x, j, 1)
                        columns = np.delete(columns, j)

         regressor_OLS.summary()
         return x, columns
    SL = 0.05
     data_modeled, selected_columns = 
     backwardElimination(data.iloc[:,1:].values, data.iloc[:,0].values, 
    SL, selected_columns)
    newfeat_formatting=list(selected_columns)
```

**IndexError: index 40 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 40**

Answer (score 0):

**I would've commented but I don't have enough rep.**

Have you tried printing out the values at each index and print the position off?

I would start with that, it sounds like an off by one error but it's hard to tell with limited scope.